# Where is the moving cat shine?

Tags: super-mario-3d-world, bowsers-fury

I have one cat shine left to collect. The map shows an exclamation mark for where it should be, but each time I check the map it's in a different spot.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot/additional detail where it is (in general)? I know there's one that moves towards the northwest corner of the map, but not sure if that's the answer I should provide.

Answer (score 3):

The moving cat shine may be on the floating island that circles around the map.

Head to the top of Mount Megameow, near where the Blue Toad is found. Equip a cat suit and wait for the island to come around. Once the island passes by, climb up and grab the cat shine.